# Restrict the number of rows in a table to be printed in a page using CSS

Tags: html, css, printing, html-table, page-break

I am having a table in a web page, I need to restrict the number of rows in the table per page (say, each printed page should contain 10 rows) (only in the printed page).

My code is like this:

```
<style>
@media print {
   thead {display: table-header-group;}
}
</style>
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>First Heading</th>
         <th>Second Heading</th>
         <th>Third Heading</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>foo</td>
         <td>bar</td>
         <td>21</td>
      </tr>
            ....
            ....
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to know, is there any possible way to do this using CSS or equivalent way?.
Also i'm having an integer values in the 3rd row, i need to print the sum of those rows in each page (say, sum of 10 rows in each page at the end of the page).

Please suggest me some ideas to achieve this. All those to be done only in the printed page not in browser display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `nth-child()` selector:

```
@media print {
  tr:nth-of-type(10n){
    page-break-after: always;
  }
}
```

This will not work in Chrome, since Chrome requires that a page-break element has to be a block level element.

There is currently no way to sum the content of a column with pure CSS, you would have to use some javascript or server-side processing.
Example:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    x=0;
    i=0;
    items=jQuery( "tbody tr" ).length;
    jQuery( "tbody tr" ).each(function(index) {
      i++;
      x = x + parseInt(jQuery("td:last-of-type",this).text());
      if (i==10 || items == index+1){
        jQuery('<tr><td colspan="2">Total:</td><td>' + x + '</td></tr>').insertAfter(this);
        x=0;
        i=0;
      }
    });
  });
```

You would then have to increase `tr:nth-of-type(10n)` to `tr:nth-of-type(11n)` since this will add a row.

Comment: This code hides all the rows after the 10th row. But i need to print the rows on the next (succeeding) pages. Each page should contain 10 rows. Help me out..

Comment: This code hides all the rows after the 10th row. But i need to print the rows on the next (succeeding) pages. Each page should contain 10 rows. Help me out..

Comment: Yeah i included.. I'm using mozilla.

Comment: Thank you... :-) Now its working... This line `jQuery('document').ready(function(){` i included...  Great answer.. :-)

Comment: can you give some idea to display the count of the integer value in each page using the server side scripting? I am using PHP.

Comment: say for ex, this is my code <style> @media print { #hid { display:block; } } #hid { display:none; } </style> <?php echo '<table>'; echo '<tr><td>Bye</td></tr>'; echo '<tr id="hid"><td>hai</td></tr>'; echo '</table>'; ?> It hides the 'hai' in both printing view and browser view.. i need to show it in the printing view... Help me.

Comment: i tried all most all property values in this link http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp
still doesn't work.

Comment: It works..:-) thank you... :-) used this `@media print {
 #hid
 {
  display:table-row;
 }
 }`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
table { page-break-inside:auto }
tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/q5phvm68/36/)

Comment: Actually, i need to restrict the count of rows to be printed in page.